# Hiding all list items except the current and next element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Only current and next element (`cNum`) is to be shown; in case it is the last element in the structure - the first element should be shown.

```
var childNum = $('#h').roundabout("getChildInFocus");
var cNum = (Number(childNum)) + 2;
if (cNum == 5) cNum = 1;

$("#h li").hide();
$("#h li:nth-child(" + cNum + ")").show();

if (cNum == 4) {
    $("#h li:nth-child(1)").show();
} else {
    $("#h li:nth-child(" + (Number(cNum) + 1).toString() + ")").show();
}
```

Comment: What is cNum used for? It's really confusing.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! With a jsFiddle or live html page, you would get more answers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few tips.

### 1)

`childNum` is not needed since it's only used once.

Old Code:

```
var childNum = $('#h').roundabout("getChildInFocus");
var cNum = (Number(childNum)) + 2;
```

New Code:

```
var cNum = $('#h').roundabout("getChildInFocus") + 2;
```

### 2)

In general, adding a object to a string results in a string.
And adding a object to a number results in a number.
Use parentheses to make the conversion clear.

Old Code:

```
$("#h li:nth-child(" + (Number(cNum) + 1).toString() + ")").show();
```

New Code:

```
$("#h li:nth-child(" + (1 + cNum) + ")").show();
```

### 3)

Cache commonly referenced elements.
Old Code:

```
$("#h li:nth-child(" + cNum + ")").show();
```

New Code:

```
var $lis = $("#h li");
$lis.find(":nth-child(" + cNum + ")").show();
```

### 4)

Combine operations on selectors.
Old Code:

```
$("#h li").hide();
$("#h li:nth-child(" + cNum + ")").show();
```

New Code:

```
$("#h li").hide().find(":nth-child(" + cNum + ")").show();
```

### 5)

Resetting the value of `cNum` to get rid of the else condition gives the following.

Old Code:

```
if (cNum == 4) {
    $("#h li:nth-child(1)").show();
} else {
    $("#h li:nth-child(" + (1+cNum) + ")").show();
}
```

New Code 1:

```
if (cNum == 4) {
    cNum = 0;
} 
$("#h li:nth-child(" + (1+cNum) + ")").show();
```

New Code 2:

```
if (cNum == 5) {
    cNum = 1;
} 
$("#h li:nth-child(" + cNum + ")").show();
```

As you can see `New Code 2` is the same from the new code in tip 4. 
So you can delete this redundant code.

### Final Code:

```
var cNum = 2 + $('#h').roundabout("getChildInFocus");
if (cNum == 5){
    cNum = 1;
}
$("#h li").hide().find(":nth-child(" + cNum + ")").show();
```